# Do I need to connect capacitor across MOV?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, circuit-protection, surge-protection, mov

I was designing some circuit for powering my module, where I need to provide protection against high voltage AC.

I found one reference from Microchip MCP39F511 where they have used MOV which is accompanied by a capacitor of high voltage rating connected in parallel to this.

I don't understand this concept. MOV used for protection against high voltage protection where it gets shorted when it finds high voltage across this. If I if connect a capacitor across this then it will hold this voltage for awhile.

I know this time is very small but this it may damage my circuit.

So can anyone help me with this to figure out that's the matter behind this.[image]

Comment: Two different things. X cap for EMI supression. MOV for overvoltage supression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems, like a small value filtering capacitor. It's purpose is to filter the high-frequency noise. It won't affect functionality of MOV.

Comment: Called an "X" cap, for reducing (along with the ferrite beads) conducted EMI generated by the switching power supply

Answer (score 2):

MOV is a voltage controlled R with some small C (pf).  For best transient immunity both clamping and C voltage divider methods are needed for **ESD with sub nanosecond rise times are faster than the diode clamps can respond or if lightning ionization via line for same reasons**, so additional bandwidth reduction methods are used such as C divider, LC LPF and clamps.

ESD is more likely if you have a floating plug and lightning when connected.

If you do not, and the ESD ionization arc time is faster than the MOV can respond and then it arcs over each subsequent parts rated for only xxx V then it will break your device.